# Node.js - Array is converted to object when sent in HTTP GET request query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, http, get

The following Node.js code:

```
var request = require('request');

var getLibs = function() {
    var options = { packages: ['example1', 'example2', 'example3'], os: 'linux', pack_type: 'npm' }

    request({url:'http://localhost:3000/package', qs:options}, 
    function (error , response, body) {
        if (! error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body);
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else{
            console.log(response.statusCode);
        }
    });
}();
```

sends the following http GET request query that is received by like this:

```
{"packages"=>{"0"=>"example1", "1"=>"example2", "2"=>"example3"}, "os"=>"linux", "pack_type"=>"npm"}
```

How can I optimize this request to be received like this:

```
{"packages"=>["example1", "example2", "example3"], "os"=>"linux", "pack_type"=>"npm"}
```

Note. The REST API is built in Ruby on Rails

Comment: I think it's expected behavior. How else would you implement sending array over get request in query param? Usually, it's sent as `?id[]=uuid1&id[]=uuid2`

Comment: I have already succeeded to send the query in the desired format using Ruby. So why the change in request format between Ruby and Node.js? And how to stop it from occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a fix. I used 'qs' to stringify 'options' with {arrayFormat : 'brackets'} and then concatinated to url ended with '?' as follows:

```
var request = require('request');
var qs1 = require('qs');

var getLibs = function() {
    var options = qs1.stringify({ 
        packages: ['example1', 'example2', 'example3'], 
        os: 'linux', 
        pack_type: 'npm' 
        },{
        arrayFormat : 'brackets'
    });


    request({url:'http://localhost:3000/package?' + options}, 
    function (error , response, body) {
        if (! error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body);
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else{
            console.log(response.statusCode);
        }
    });
}();
```

Note: I tried to avoid concatenation to url, but all responses had code 400

Answer (score 1):

If the array need to be received as it is, you can set `useQuerystring` as `true`:

UPDATE: `list` key in the following code example has been changed to `'list[]'`, so that OP's ruby backend can successfully parse the array.

Here is example code:

```
const request = require('request');

let data = {
  'name': 'John',
  'list[]': ['XXX', 'YYY', 'ZZZ']
};

request({
  url: 'https://requestb.in/1fg1v0i1',
  qs: data,
  useQuerystring: true
}, function(err, res, body) {
  // ...
});
```

In this way, when the HTTP `GET` request is sent, the query parameters would be:

```
?name=John&list[]=XXX&list[]=YYY&list[]=ZZZ
```

and the `list` field would be parsed as `['XXX', 'YYY', 'ZZZ']`

---

Without `useQuerystring` (default value as `false`), the query parameters would be:

```
?name=John&list[][0]=XXX&list[][1]=YYY&list[][2]=ZZZ
```

Comment: The query was received like you mentioned : 
?packages=example1&packages=example2&packages=example3.....
but not parsed as an array. instead it became  {"packages"=>"uuid", "os"=>"linux", "pack_type"=>"npm"}

Comment: The query in my Ruby code was sent as: 
?packages[]=example1&packages[]=example2&packages[]=example3.....
Then parsed to: {packages = ['example1', 'example2', 'example3'], ......}

Comment: @TamerB Then you can use `packages[]` as the key of data. I've edited the answer.

Comment: This will send "packages" as an array with one object inside it. i.e. The request will be like this: {"packages"=>[{"0"=>"example1","1"=>"example2","2"=>"example3"}]....}.
Any way, I finally found an idea that solved my problem. Please find my answer. Thank you for your effort :)

Comment: Thanks @TamerB but I'm a bit confused. You mentioned in the Ruby code (which works) the query is `?packages[]=xxx&packages[]=yyy&packages[]=zzz`. But that is exact what `useQuerystring: true` do. Very weird...

Comment: I don't have enough experience to comment on this. But in my case, for some reason, with `useQuerystring: true` the query becomes `{"packages"=>"uuid", "os"=>"linux", "pack_type"=>"npm"}`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using Request library itself. 
Request internally uses qs.stringify. You can pass q option to request which it will use to parse array params.

You don't need to append to url which leaves reader in question why that would have been done.

Reference: https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback

> ```
> const options = {
>   method: 'GET',
>   uri: 'http://localhost:3000/package',
>   qs: {
>     packages: ['example1', 'example2', 'example3'], 
>     os: 'linux', 
>     pack_type: 'npm' 
>   },
>   qsStringifyOptions: {
>     arrayFormat: 'repeat' // You could use one of indices|brackets|repeat
>   },
>   json: true
> };
> ```